# simultaneous inverse fast fourier transform of two real functions

Tags: floating-point, signal-processing, fft, ifft, real-datatype

I'm trying to calculate the inverse Fourier Transform of two real functions with a single IFFT. The best and most straightforward explanation I've found so far is [here](http://www.dsprelated.com/showmessage/38405/1.php), where it says:

> Use the fact that the FFT is linear and form the sum of the first transform plus i times the second.
>   You have two vectors, x1 and x2, with
>   discrete Fourier Transforms X1 and X2
>   respectively. Then
>
> x1 = Re[ IDFT[ X1 + i X2 ] ]
>
> and
>
> x2 = Im[ IDFT[ X1 + i X2 ] ].

The problem is that I don't get where the 'i' parameter comes from.
Any hint on this would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

After doing some experiments I finally made it work, but now I'm more confused than before as it didn't work as I expected and had to use some imagination to figure out the correct formulas.

I just made up a new complex array where:

```
Re[n] = X1Re[n] - X2Im[n]
Im[n] = X2Re[n] + X1Im[n]
```

After doing an IFFT on it x1 = Re and x2 = Im, so wouldn't it be correct to express it like this?

```
x1 = Re[ IDFT[ X1 - i X2 ] ]
x2 = Im[ IDFT[ X2 + i X1 ] ].
```

Comment: Just out of interest, what is the use case for doing an IFFT on real data ? While real-valued time domain signals are of course very common I've never seen purely real frequency domain signals ?

Comment: The IFFT is made on the output of a single FFT which was fed with two real signals. Sorry I think I didn't make myself clear :)

Comment: @eryksun You're right I transcribed it wrong, thanks

Comment: [Here's a related question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959289/efficient-2d-fft-on-real-input-data)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you wondering what the 'i' represents?  In this case, I believe 'i' is referring to sqrt(-1), the imaginary unit vector.

Then:

```
Re[ IDFT[ X1 + i X2 ] ]
```

will be the 'real' part of that transform (anything without an 'i') and

```
Im[ IDFT[ X1 + i X2 ] ]
```

will be the 'imaginary' part of that transform (anything multiplied by an 'i').

It is possible I've misunderstood your question and this answer is much too simplistic; if it is, no insult was intended to your intelligence, I just misunderstood you.

Comment: The "plus i times the second" part is what keeps me wondering. I'm no math guru nor I pretend to be, I just want to add this functionality to my FFT lib while having a little understanding of what it's really doing :)

Comment: It's because of the linearity of FFT, which means it respects addition and scalar multiplication.  (i.e. F(a + bc) = F(a) + cF(b).  You can exploit this to write your 2 transforms as 1.  So instead of doing F(a) first and F(b) next, you do F(a +bi), and then F(a) = anything without an i, and F(b) = anything with an i.  'i' in this case just works like any constant.  It's like.... a really advanced way of rewriting (x - 2x + 2) as (x - 2x + 1) + 1 so you can write (x-1)^2 + 1.  They're all the same thing, it's just easier to work with one of them.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ignore the mathematics of complex variables, multiplying by i is just notation for how you swap and scale a pair of vectors to produce another pair of vectors.  And the complex vectors X1 and X2 can each be considered to be just pairs of real-valued vectors (with a "complex" relationship under the transforms of interest).  The swap and scale makes the two component vectors more easily separable, after some arithmetic and transforms, into the real valued vector of interest.